# Can I disable the camera button on my 920?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

I'm annoyed by the camera button on my phone. It wakes my phone up when I press it! Is there any way to disable the wake-up feature of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to settings. Swipe to get to application and open settings for "photos + camera". There would be a checkbox saying "Press and hold camera button to wake up the phone". Unchecking it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to settings and swipe right, which is the app settings.
You'll see the photo + camera and when you click, uncheck the wake up feature. Just that

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of the existing answer, providing no additional information.